# Make API call to Office365 Graph

Tags: c#, json, office365

I want to send Office365 Graph HTTP requests using C#.

For eg.
Graph query : `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`
will fetch all the users in a `json` format.

So I need to do with the help of C# so that I can easily play with json and can print those users in my console.

Comment: Where did you got stuck? Making the api call or deserializing the json response?

Comment: What's the question? So far this is just a statement of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please share some findings or code of yours to check the exact problem.

Comment: How to send the query using C#

Comment: @croxy making the api call

Answer (score 1):

Doing the api call would look something like that:

```
string json = null;
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users");
    if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
{
    // Do something with your json
}
```

To be able to work with the returned json data I suggest using [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

**Note:**

The type `HttpClient` lives in the Namespace `System.Net.Http`, so don't forget to add:

```
using System.Net.Http;
```